# Get environment of function from within the function

Tags: r, environment

I want to define a function in an environment, which uses globals from this environment:

```r
e <- new.env()
e$a <- 1
e$f <- function() a

## e$f()
## Error in e$f() : object 'a' not found

environment(e$f) <- e
e$f()
# [1] 1
```

So far so good. Now assume I add another (locked) binding to `e`:

```r
e$b <- 2
lockBinding("b", e)
```

How could I (temporarily) unlock this binding from within `f` **without** using the symbol `e`?

```r
e$f <- function() unlockBinding("b", parent.frame())
environment(e$f) <- e
e$f()
```

does not work because `parent.frame` does not properly point to `e`.

---

I do not want to use `e` directly because this would break as soon as I clone environments:

```r
e <- new.env()
e$a <- e$b <- 1
lockBinding("b", e)
e$f <- function() unlockBinding("b", e)
environment(e$f) <- e
## e$b <- 3
## Error in e$b <- 3 : cannot change value of locked binding for 'b'

g <- rlang::env_clone(e)
g$f()
e$b <- 3 ## should not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the solution:

```r
e$f <- function() unlockBinding("b", parent.env(environment()))
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The proto package facilitates this sort of thing avoiding most explicit mucking with environments. A proto object is an environment with the class proto that has its own methods. See the package vignette for more information.

```
library(proto)

# create proto object containing 3 objects
p <- proto(a = 1, b = 1, f = function(.) unlockBinding("b", .))

p$lockBinding(sym = "b")  # lock b
p$b <- 3 # error since p$b is locked

p2 <- as.proto(p$as.list()) # clone p
p2$b <- 4 # ok since p2 is distinct from p

p$b <- 3  # as expected, this is an error since p$b is locked

ch <- p$proto() # create a child of p
ch$b  # b is not in ch so it finds it in parent p
## [1] 1

ch$b <- 10  # ok since this creates a new b in ch overriding p$b

p$f() # unlock b
p$b <- 20  # ok
```

Comment: Beautiful, always love to learn about new useful packages. My use case is that I want to provide a sandbox environment in which R code from my shiny app can be "safely" evaluated (safe in a sense that end users need to go to some pain to shoot themselves in the foot). For this I overwrite package loading functions to log all new loaded packages such that they can be unloaded after the code is `eval'ed`. Since all users of this shiny app have anyways connection to the very machine, I just really need a safeguard for inadvertently overwriting symbols from the shiny app itself.

Comment: For this use case, however, the `proto` package seems a bit like an overkill (with yet another dependency), but deffo somehting to be used in the future.